# Cant get hierarchic properties by S3 Backend spring config server

Tags: amazon-s3, spring-cloud-config-server

I created spring config server with s3 backend as it described here:
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_aws_s3_backend

I created 4 files in my-config-server s3 bucket:

```
app-default.properties
app-dev.properties
client-app-default.properties
client-app-dev.properties
```

When I ran client-app application  with dev profile, I got **only** client-app-dev.properties properties.

I am interested if it is possible to get also ***client-app-default.properties***, ***app-dev.properties*** and ***app-default.properties properties***, if its were not defined in ***client-app-dev.properties***

In another words, Is it possible to support following hierarchic:

```
application.properties # Applicable for all environments.
  application-dev.properties # Environment level commons across all services.
    client-app-dev.properties # Overrides specific to the service for one environment.
    client-app2-dev.properties
```

for example:

```
client-app-dev.properties
  my.property1="my-propertyDev1"

client-app-default.properties
  my.property1="my-propertyDefault1"
  my.property2="my-property2Default"

app-default.properties
  my.property3="my-propertyAppDefault3"
```

when I am running client-app application with dev profile I what to get:

```
@Value("${my.property1}")
private String property1; //"my-propertyDev1"

@Value("${my.property2}")
private String property2; //"my-property2Default"

@Value("${my.property3}")
private String property3; //"my-propertyAppDefault3"
```

It works so with regular spring config server but I didn't succeed with s3 backed. It goes directly to specific app and specific profile